# The $\rm SO(8)$ invariant interaction piece in Fidkowski and Kitaev's model

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase, majorana-fermions

In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.81.134509) ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2197)), the authors demonstrate the existence of a quartic interaction $W$ involving the 8 majorana operators $c_1 \ldots c_8$ (eq. 8) which is invariant under an $\rm SO(7)$ symmetry that can produce a unique ground state invariant under $\rm SO(7)$ as well as time-reversal. They also demonstrate that an $\rm SO(8)$ invariant interaction, which they call V, does not work. I want to know the precise form of V which is not explicitly stated in their paper. The only thing the authors say is that V is also quartic in the fermion operators (above eq. 15) and is related to the quadratic Casimir.

I am confused because the 16-dimensional Hilbert space transforms as the spinor representation of $\rm SO(8)$ and is reducible into the two chiral irreps ($8_+$ and $8_-$). From Schur's lemma, the only $\rm SO(8)$ invariant term that can be written is proportional to the projector onto the two 8-dimensional irreps. Since the two irreps are distinguished by the eigenvalue of the chirality operator ($\Gamma_c \sim c_1 c_2 \ldots c_8$), I would think that the term V is proportional to $\Gamma_c$. But this is clearly not quartic.